# Count how many times a word can be formed with a given set of string

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to get how many times a word can be **formed** from a given random string of lowercase alphabets.

**Example** Suppose I have a string `hfgajjvbynajgrty` and I would like to know how many times my name `ayan` can be formed from it.

I did a bit but after that I am not being able to think the logic to do it.

```
$result = [];
$count = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$stringLength; $i++) {
    $count = substr_count($string, $string[$i]);
    $result[$string[$i]] = $count;
}
var_dump($result);

foreach($result as $s => $occurs) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very easy but it's not hard too...

Suppose you wanna make the word `abc` and you are given the string `aaabbbbccc`.

the first thing to do is create an array A that will contain the number of occurrences of the chars in the word you want (obviously an array of length 26).

the second thing is to create another array B that will contain the number of occurrencies of the chars in the string you were given (also length 26).

in this example, the arrays are:

```
A: 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: 3 4 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

then you run the following loop:

```
int answer = 99999999;
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    if(A[i] != 0){
        answer = min(answer, B[i]/A[i]);
    }
}
```

your answer will store the maximum possible number of times A can be made with B.

In the example case, answer will be 3 (which is the minimum between {3,4,3} and obviously you will waste one `b`).

if the given string were `aabbbcccc`, the answer would be 2, which is the minimum between {2,3,4}.

Comment: It works in most cases but not all cases. Certain test cases failed. I am not sure why.

Comment: can you tell me a case where it doesn't work? I'm pretty sure it's right unless I understood wrongly what you want

Comment: Well its a big Case, it consists of 95638 characters.

Comment: are you sure it contains only (a...z) ?

Comment: you can take a look here http://pastebin.com/YW2CaHfJ . It contains my whole code plus a sample set.

Comment: well, I can just ask if you are filling the arrays correctly and if the division `B[i]/A[i]` is an integer division (meaning that it wont return you something like 3.3)

Comment: I am rounding of the quotient to floor value. For ex: 3.3 will become 3. And yes according to few array dumps I saw value properly at respective indexes. Still you can check my code for flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for this using Java Maps.

```
public int findCount(String word, String inputString) {
    Map<Character, Integer> mapWord = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (mapWord.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {
            int oldV = mapWord.get(word.charAt(i));
            mapWord.put(word.charAt(i), ++oldV);
        } else {
            mapWord.put(word.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }

    Map<Character, Integer> mapInputString = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        if (mapInputString.containsKey(inputString.charAt(i))) {
            int oldV = mapInputString.get(inputString.charAt(i));
            mapInputString.put(inputString.charAt(i), ++oldV);
        } else {
            mapInputString.put(inputString.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }

    int currentCharacterCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    if (mapWord.equals(mapInputString))
        return 1;

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : mapWord.entrySet()) {

        if (!mapInputString.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (mapInputString.get(entry.getKey()) < entry.getValue()) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (mapInputString.get(entry.getKey()) >= entry.getValue()) {
            currentCharacterCount = mapInputString.get(entry.getKey()) / entry.getValue();
        }

        if (count == 0 || currentCharacterCount <= count) {
            count = currentCharacterCount;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```